# iOS - CMSampleBufferRef is not being released from captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I am capturing frames from the camera using the code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
        :(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerCapturedFrame:withFrameImage:withFrameBuffer:)]) {
        [delegate captureManagerCapturedFrame:self withFrameImage:image withFrameBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    }

}
```

I am doing this because in the delegate method `captureManagerCapturedFrame:withFrameImage:withFrameBuffer:` I have a flag which tells the app to use either the returned `uiimage` OR the returned `sampleBuffer`.

The delegate method is:

```
- (void) captureManagerCapturedFrame:(AVCamCaptureManager *)captureManager
                      withFrameImage:(UIImage *)image
                     withFrameBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)frameBuffer {

    if(_screen1) {
        NSLog(@"Only display camera image\n");
    }
    else if(_screen2) {
        //Enable IR
        NSLog(@"Display AND Process camera image\n");
        [self imageReconigitionProcessFrame:frameBuffer];
    }
}
```

where `imageReconigitionProcessFrame:` is:

```
-(void)imageReconigitionProcessFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)frameBuffer {

    //CFRetain(frameBuffer);
    MSImage *qry = [[MSImage alloc] initWithBuffer:frameBuffer orientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait]; //MEMORY LEAK HERE???
    qry = nil;
    //CFRelease(frameBuffer);
}
```

This code effectively works. **But here is my problem.** When this code is run and profiled in instruments, I see a rapid increase in the `overall bytes` used, but the allocations profiler doesn't appear to increase. Nor do a see any 'leaks' using the leaks tool. But clearly, there is a rapid memory gain each time `imageReconigitionProcessFrame:` is called and the app crashes after a few seconds. When I set `frameBuffer` to `nil`, there is NO increase in memory (or course I also don't have the frame buffer to do any processing with).

I have tried transfering ownership of `frameBuffer` using `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` (commented out in the above code), but these don't seem to do anything either.

**Does anyone have any idea where I could be leaking memory inside this function???**
The method `[[MSImage alloc] initWithBuffer:` is form a third party SDK ([Moodstocks](http://www.moodstocks.com), which is an awesome image recognition SDK) and it works just fine in their demos, so I don't think the problem is inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for mentioning Moodstocks (I work for them): we're happy that you find our SDK useful!

To answer your question, I guess your code does indeed contain a leak: at the end of the `imageReconigitionProcessFrame` method, you should call `[qry release]`. The rule in Obj-C is quite simple: whenever you manually call `alloc` on an object, it should also be manually released!

That's BTW what is done in the [Moodstocks SDK](https://developers.moodstocks.com) wrapper: if you look at the `[MSScannerSession session: didOutputSampleBuffer:]` method, you'll see that we do manually release the `MSImage` object after it's been processed.

As to why the profiler doesn't find this leak, I guess that it's due to the fact that leaks are analyzed every 10 seconds by default: in this case, the memory leak is so heavy (1280x720 frames, at 15+ FPS if you're on an iPhone 5, for 10 seconds: at least 130 MB leaked) that the code must crash before the first 10 seconds are reached.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My project is ARC enabled, so adding a `[qry release]` statement is a no go. I've tried adding the `[[MSImage alloc] initWithBuffer:` to the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection` method directly (instead of passing the buffer back through the delegate class, and the same problem persists.

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with ARC unfortunately... I'm usually the Android developer here :D. Nonetheless, I would try checking that the `[MSImage dealloc]` method is called: if so, then the object responsible for the leak is not `qry` but something else...

Comment: `[MSImage dealloc]` is in fact being called. This is another reason why I am thinking it's related to the frame buffer, and not the MSImage creation.

Comment: I'm still not sure if this is a Moodstocks issue or not, but I'm sending an email to help.moodstocks.com with a demo app that reproduces the issue. Demo is hosted at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4402291/AVCam-MoodstocksLeakDemo.zip

Comment: If you Profile it in instruments (with allocations), you should see the "Overall Bytes" value go up to over a gb - then it should crash. Is that value stable in your environment? Could you email me at: brett.spurrier (at) gmail (dot) com. Maybe we could hash out the details that are unimportant to other SO readers. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the "Overall Bytes" column actually. Shoot me an email and I can tell you more details.